# Can NHibernate LINQ syntax support double constants when comparing integer properties?

Tags: nhibernate

This NHibernate query seems to use use an integer data type for the constant parameter, causing wrong results:

```
double myValue = 1.5;
Session.Query<Foo>().Where(x => x.IntProp < myValue*x.AnotherIntProp).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Works On My Machine against SQL-server 2008 dialect, generating the following SQL on NHibernate 4.0.4.4000 according to NHibernate profiler:

```
select fooentity0_.Id             as Id3_,
   fooentity0_.IntProp        as IntProp3_,
   fooentity0_.AnotherIntProp as AnotherI3_3_
from   [FooEntity] fooentity0_
where  cast(fooentity0_.IntProp as FLOAT(53)) < 1.5 /* @p0 */ * cast(fooentity0_.AnotherIntProp as FLOAT(53))
```

So I guess it is a dialect-specific bug, which dialect are you using?